# Qt Error: Searching for a function that does not exist

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I have a function called `LoadImage` in my Qt project.  When I try to build the problem, Qt complains `error: no 'QImage Utils::LoadImageW(QString)...`

I do not have any function called `LoadImageW`, and I have never written a function called `LoadImageW`.  What is going wrong here?

Comment: _"What is going wrong here?"_ External dependencies?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Not sure why being downvoted.

Comment: Sometimes, when you see a name you're unfamiliar with, you need to google it. Or, alternatively, work on a minimal test case. Had you minimized your code, you realize that getting rid of the windows platform includes "fixes" the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It clashes with WinApi function [`LoadImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx). And in WinApi there are always two versions - ascii (`LoadImageA`) and wide (`LoadImageW`) character.

Unfortunately the translation is done in preprocessor so whenever there is a clash, it transforms user code too.

Fortunately, WinApi is the only using capitalized CamelCase so as long as you follow lower camelCase, it's enough to avoid any clashes. So just choose loadImage here.